# Outputting all regression coefficients for a regression loop in R using sapply?

Tags: r, for-loop, output, regression, coefficients

I’m new to R, coding and stack overflow. I’m trying to run a multiple linear regression for each level of the ordinal variable 'Age'. Age has 10 possible integer values. All the other variables are continuous.

I partially managed to get the regression outputs at each level of 'Age', but I can’t figure out how to display a full summary table of coefficients for each level in the loop.

Here’s what I mean: When I run the regression subset for Age==1 I get the following summary output:

```
##Regression for Age==1
Final_Frame.df <- read_csv("mydata.csv")
dim(Final_Frame.df)


Age_1=Final_Frame.df[Final_Frame.df$Age==1,]

dim(Age_1)
Effects_lm=lm(Product_Sum~Mean_social_combined +
  Mean_traditional_time+
  Mean_Passive_Use_Updated+
  Mean_Active_Use_Updated, data=Age_1)

summary(Effects_lm)
```

Here is the output

```
Call:
lm(formula = Product_Sum ~ Mean_social_combined + Mean_traditional_time + 
    Mean_Passive_Use_Updated + Mean_Active_Use_Updated, data = Age_1)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-23.367 -11.079  -2.066   9.540  48.903 

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)                15.485      7.491   2.067   0.0444 *
Mean_social_combined       -1.086      5.625  -0.193   0.8477  
Mean_traditional_time       1.310      3.311   0.396   0.6942  
Mean_Passive_Use_Updated   -3.004      3.377  -0.889   0.3784  
Mean_Active_Use_Updated     9.130      5.914   1.544   0.1295  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 15.92 on 46 degrees of freedom
  (5 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.05779,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.02414 
F-statistic: 0.7053 on 4 and 46 DF,  p-value: 0.5924

             (Intercept)     Mean_social_combined    Mean_traditional_time Mean_Passive_Use_Updated 
              10.1801725                0.5982227                0.2666642               -1.7716028 
 Mean_Active_Use_Updated 
              11.6577843
```

But when I run it for all levels, I don't get the same amount of information. The closest I've gotten is using .coefs, which only produces the regression coefficients.

```
##Functionalisation
my.JORT.lm=function(Age.df) {coef(lm(Product_Sum~Mean_social_combined +
  Mean_traditional_time+
  Mean_Passive_Use_Updated+
  Mean_Active_Use_Updated, data=Age.df))}

##Split age level

Age.by.level=split(Final_Frame.df, f=Final_Frame.df$Age)

class(Age.by.level)
names(Age.by.level)

#Regression output for all 10 levels of age

Final_Frame2.df=sapply(Age.by.level, FUN=my.JORT.lm)

Final_Frame2.df.coefs
```

OUTPUT

```
                                 1         2          3          4          5         6         7         8         9
(Intercept)              15.485342 19.671566 -2.6799874   6.707780 -2.9383992  6.074756  6.535079 -2.833462  4.070595
Mean_social_combined     -1.086346  6.727591  6.3753196   2.006972  2.2910173 -3.647688 -7.492282 -3.232723 -1.590179
Mean_traditional_time     1.309759 -2.017883  0.6843741   4.795550  1.4745771  2.983761  4.227461  5.406311  1.985889
Mean_Passive_Use_Updated -3.003786 -8.415782 -2.8591079   4.999754 -0.6350261  5.354196  5.413747  3.588647  5.573119
Mean_Active_Use_Updated   9.129950 15.154421 10.5226187 -11.222790  9.7848515 -3.432742 -2.406095  2.851160 -4.111706
                                 10
(Intercept)              -18.799694
Mean_social_combined      24.837171
Mean_traditional_time      1.043116
Mean_Passive_Use_Updated   3.725663
Mean_Active_Use_Updated   -6.127393
```

When I attempted to retrieve the r squared and adjusted r squared using $rsq I get "Error in Final_Frame2.df$rsq : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". Could someone let me know how to replicate the output for Age==1 for the more complex regression? I particularly need the p values, the r2 and the adjusted r2s. I hope the question is sufficiently clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it all with `by` if all you want is the summary.  Here's an example with `mtcars`.

```
my.fun <- function(df){summary(lm(mpg ~ hp + drat, data=df))}
by(mtcars, list(mtcars$cyl), my.fun)

# : 4
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ hp + drat, data = df)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
# -3.038 -2.580 -1.433  1.670  7.306 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 22.58423   20.15984   1.120    0.295
# hp          -0.08962    0.07144  -1.254    0.245
# drat         2.82123    4.09205   0.689    0.510
# 
# Residual standard error: 4.174 on 8 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.3148,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.1435 
# F-statistic: 1.837 on 2 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.2205
# 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#   : 6
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ hp + drat, data = df)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Mazda RX4  Mazda RX4 Wag Hornet 4 Drive        Valiant       Merc 280      Merc 280C 
# 0.9964         0.9964         1.7704        -1.4315        -0.6885        -2.0885 
# Ferrari Dino 
# 0.4453 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
# (Intercept) 19.276291   5.955542   3.237   0.0318 *
#   hp          -0.009557   0.030111  -0.317   0.7668  
# drat         0.456031   1.534477   0.297   0.7811  
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 1.747 on 4 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.0374,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.4439 
# F-statistic: 0.07771 on 2 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.9266
# 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#   : 8
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ hp + drat, data = df)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -3.9390 -1.1833  0.1403  1.6083  3.5607 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
# (Intercept) 11.57381    6.29341   1.839    0.093 .
# hp          -0.02861    0.01840  -1.555    0.148  
# drat         2.94579    2.51872   1.170    0.267  
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 2.517 on 11 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.1822,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.03345 
# F-statistic: 1.225 on 2 and 11 DF,  p-value: 0.3309
```

---

### Edit: Return coefs, p-vals and R2

```
my.fun <- function(df){
  s <- summary(m <- lm(mpg ~ hp + drat, data=df))
  b <- coef(m)
  p <- s$coef[,4]
  bp <- c(rbind(b, p))
  names(bp) <- c(rbind(names(b), paste(names(b), "p", sep="_")))
  out <- c(bp, r2 = s$r.squared, r2.adj = s$adj.r.squared)
  out
}

sapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl), function(x)my.fun(x))
#                         4            6           8
# (Intercept)   22.58423314 19.276290671 11.57380765
# (Intercept)_p  0.29510529  0.031773165  0.09303542
# hp            -0.08961637 -0.009556567 -0.02861472
# hp_p           0.24508497  0.766829526  0.14815496
# drat           2.82123087  0.456031349  2.94579083
# drat_p         0.51004482  0.781115913  0.26689654
# r2             0.31476959  0.037400884  0.18215026
# r2.adj         0.14346199 -0.443898674  0.03345031
```

Comment: Suggesting writing by line as: by(mtcars, mtcars["cyl"], my.fun)

Comment: Thank you @DaveArmstrong! Using by()  does indeed work but I would like everything to display in one table as shown in my output. I wasn't able to figure out how to do that using by(). Is there a way to do so? Thank you!

Comment: @Socsi2 I edited the answer to include what I think you want.  Let me know if otherwise.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I wanted but it doesn't quite work for my purposes: It returns 12 outputs for Age when there should only be 10 (I previously consolidated 12 levels into 10 due to a small number of observations in the tails) and the labels are shifted

Comment: Without having access to your data, I don’t  know how to help further.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong I had a typo in my code. Once it was fixed, your solution worked perfectly. Thank you so much!